# Trigger Function Permissions Issue in Supabase: Access Denied for Function Called by Trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, supabase

I'm encountering an issue while working with Supabase triggers and function execution permissions. I have set up a trigger to fire after an insert into the `auth.users` table. The trigger calls a function named `public.handle_new_user()` which performs certain actions, including inserting data into another table `public.profiles`.

Here's a summary of what I've done:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS on_auth_user_created ON auth.users;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE LOG 'Current user: %', current_user;

    PERFORM public.insert_into_profiles(
        NEW.id,
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'first_name'),
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'last_name')      
    );

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER on_auth_user_created
AFTER INSERT ON auth.users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user();
```

When I execute `insert_into_profiles()` in the Supabase dashboard, it works correctly because it's executed as the `postgres` user. However, when this function is invoked in the `handle_new_user()` function and by the trigger after an `INSERT` (triggered by supabase_auth_admin), I encounter a "permission denied" error specifically for the `public.profiles` table.

Any insights on why the function called by the trigger doesn't have the required permissions, especially when the function itself works when executed independently?

Thank you for any help or guidance!

I've verified that the `public.insert_into_profiles` function works correctly when executed directly:

```
SELECT public.insert_into_profiles(
    'b53e07f1-e775-4a15-b287-8a25d3525bca',
    'John',
    'Doe'
);
```

This command executes without issues. However, within the `handle_new_user()` context, it seems to lack the necessary permissions.

Also I've removed all Row Level Security (RLS) policies, and the error still persists

Comment: Found the solution, [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/permissions) I found that the `supabase_auth_admin` only owns the `auth` schema, and therefore has no right for the public schema. I could not tell you how to reporoduce this error. Because in the begin in the project I didn't have this error. If you also get this error;
just grant the correct privileges to  `supabase_auth_admin` for instance: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE public.profiles TO supabase_auth_admin;`

Comment: [It's ok to post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Just make sure there's no earlier thread you can improve in case this would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your function a security definer so that it has Postgres privileges.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER
security definer
AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE LOG 'Current user: %', current_user;

    PERFORM public.insert_into_profiles(
        NEW.id,
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'first_name'),
        (NEW.raw_user_meta_data->>'last_name')      
    );

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```